# Why doesn't extract-vmlinux work with Raspbian's /boot/kernel*.img?

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel, raspberry-pi-os, monitoring

To monitor if a reboot is necessary, I wanted to compare the version of `/boot/kernel*img` against the version of the running kernel.

To get the kernel version of a compressed linux kernel image (usually called *zImage* and named `vmlinuz` with a `z` for *zipped* instead of an `x` at the end), it suffices (at least on Debian) to look for the kernel version (major + minor + ABI + architecture) of the file name to get the exact kernel version (major + minor + micro), e.g. like this:

```
$ strings /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 | egrep '^4\.9\.0-8-amd64'
4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21)
4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21)
```

But on Raspbian 9 Stretch as well as 8 Jessie (with kernels from the Raspberry Pi Foundation as common on Raspbian images provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation) this information is not found just with `strings`:

```
$ strings /tmp/kernel7.img | head -30
@ #!
!1C "
 -- System halted
Attempting division by 0!
stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted
Uncompressing Linux...
 done, booting the kernel.
decompressor returned an error
[…]
Out of memory while allocating workspace
Not a gzip file
header error
read error
uncompression error
```

The only thing that I see is that this seems a `gzip`-compressed kernel (due to a `gzip` error message being compiled in). Also `file` says, that this is a zImage:

```
$ file /boot/kernel*.img
/boot/kernel7.img: Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
/boot/kernel.img:  Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
```

But I'm unable to extract the uncompressed *vmlinux* from these kernel images files, even with [`extract-vmlinux` directly off Linus' Linux git repository](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/raw/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux) and having installed all (de)compression tools it supports:

```
$ extract-vmlinux /boot/kernel7.img
extract-vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux.
```

Looking at which uncompression methods it actually tries, it seems indeed to think that this is either a `gzip`- or `zstd`-compressed file:

```
$ sh -x `which extract-vmlinux` /boot/kernel7.img 2>&1 | fgrep -A1 tail
+ tail -c+18273 /boot/kernel7.img
+ gunzip
--
+ tail -c+566153 /boot/kernel7.img
+ gunzip
--
+ tail -c+2494526 /boot/kernel7.img
+ gunzip
--
+ tail -c+4195668 /boot/kernel7.img
+ unzstd
```

So independent from my initial motivation, I'd like to know:

- Why is even `extract-vmlinux` unable to extract the uncompressed kernel image from Raspbian's `/boot/kernel*.img` images?
- What do I need to extract the uncompressed kernel image from Raspbian's `/boot/kernel*.img` images?

EDIT: Addendum from late February 2023: This does not apply to RaspiOS' 64-bit `kernel8.img` kernel images, but still is the case with e.g. `kernel7l.img`.

But on the other hand, the latter looks even more weird with `file` nowadays. Then maybe, `file` is more precise these days and that's actually the reason for this issue:

```
# file /boot/kernel*
/boot/kernel7l.img: ARM OpenFirmware FORTH Dictionary, Text length: -509607936 bytes, Data length: -509607936 bytes, Text Relocation Table length: -369098747 bytes, Data Relocation Table length: 24061976 bytes, Entry Point: 0x00000000, BSS length: 7051064 bytes
/boot/kernel8.img:  gzip compressed data, was "Image", last modified: Thu Jan  5 12:03:14 2023, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 22057472
```

Comment: I believe the reason you can't extract the kernel from the image file is because of the binary blog *proprietary magic* compiled in by Broadcom.... but I may be wrong.

Comment: AFAIK that binary blob stuff from Broadcom is [just prepended](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/mkimage/imagetool-uncompressed.py). And `extract-vmlinux` searches for typical start markers of compression and only tries to decompress from there on.  It also decides which decompression method to try based on which markers were found.

Comment: Well... I haven't tried yet... but here are the instructions to [build your own RPi kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) ... If you are looking to verify kernels, you could probably do a sha256 hash and compare rather than look for strings in binaries.

Comment: No, hashsums would require to know them to be able to compare them. I'm looking to expand an existing and so far rather generic solution to work with Raspbian, too. (So far works fine on Debian and Ubuntu with their stock kernels.)

Comment: Related reports: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352215/how-do-i-extract-vmlinux-from-an-arm-image and https://bugs.linaro.org/show_bug.cgi?id=461